# How to mask a raster and apply an unsupervised classification? R

Tags: r, land-classification, terra, spatial-cluster

I am getting the error:

```
In matrix(values, nrow = ncell(x), ncol = nlayers(x)) :
data length [6691] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [25628]. In reaction to knr <- setValues(rgb, kmncluster$cluster)
```

I have seen that str(nr) gives the number of rows 25628, and str(kmncluster) gives the number of rows 6691. I have a feeling that the nr file has included the crop area with no raster values, and the kmncluster has excluded these values so it struggles to produce the raster layer.

How would I go about excluding the values which has no raster information in the rgb raster stack?
Have I identified the issue correctly or is there something else to it?

```
library(sp)
library(tidyverse)
library(raster) 
library(terra)
library(geodata)
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

blue = raster("Landsat/LC08_L2SP_203032_20221012_20221020_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_203032_20221012_20221020_02_T1_SR_B2.TIF")
green = raster("Landsat/LC08_L2SP_203032_20221012_20221020_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_203032_20221012_20221020_02_T1_SR_B3.TIF")
red = raster("Landsat/LC08_L2SP_203032_20221012_20221020_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_203032_20221012_20221020_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF")

shape1 <- read_sf(file.path("Shapefiles/Ermo-aguias-limits_02.2022.shp"))

shp1 <- st_transform(shape1, crs(rgb))

shp1<-st_zm(shp1)

rgb = stack(red, green, blue)

rgb<- mask(crop(rgb,shp1),shp1)

nr <- getValues(rgb)

kmncluster <- kmeans(na.omit(nr), centers = 5, iter.max = 500, nstart = 5, algorithm="Lloyd")

knr <- setValues(rgb, kmncluster$cluster)

knr <- raster(rgb)

values(knr) <- kmncluster$cluster

plot(knr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you applied a crop, then computed kmeans using only pixels with observed values, the `setValues` is trying to fill all pixels with the values provided, even NA pixels, and fails. The error message is telling you this issue:

> data length [6691] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of
> rows [25628].

Also, you are trying to set values of a a multi-layer raster using a single-layer output (only one cluster analysis)

Fill only the pixels with observed values and use only single-layer raster, no a multi-layer raster:

```
r = blue
r[!is.na(r)] = kmncluster$cluster
```